# How to view total triggered run-time today

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing code which is running on triggers. I know that I have 1 hour of triggered run time per day. Can I access how much of this hour I have used? Or can I log how much I used at the end of the day so I can know if I am in danger of going over this quota?

Thank you,
Eric

Comment: I can't find an built-in way of getting the trigger quota used for the day.  There might be a way to time the length of the script, and then record each result to a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can make use of Apps Script REST API to achieve this. Specifically, the [REST Resource: processes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/processes#resource:-process) one.

Please refer to the **duration** field as displayed here -

[image]